# GWT i18n HTML files

Tags: java, html, gwt

I have already provided GWT's i18n feature for java, UI Binder and trying to provide i18n with pure, none-hosted in java HTML file.

After reading "[Declarative Layout with UiBinder](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder#Hello_Text_%20Resources)" I implement some code, but it didn't work:

```
<html xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder">
<ui:with field='i18n' type='//.exampleConstants'/>
  <head>
   <title>Title of none-hosted HTML file and i18n part: <ui:text from='{i18n.title}'/></title>
 </head>
 <body>
  ...
 </body>
</html>
```

The solution with id's (described on same page: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/i18n/) which will be pick-upped by RootPanel, smth like:

```
RootPanel.get("appTitle").add(new Label(constants.stockWatcher()));
```

Didn't work too, because my HTML file isn't bundled with Java.

How to do i18n in HTML files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you'd have a Catch-22 here: the HTML file couldn't *know* which text to use until the JavaScript compiled out of your Java code is loaded, which is done by the page, so after it's loaded.

You have to use *standard Java web app techniques* to internationalize your HTML page, e.g. make it a JSP, and detect the preferred language out of the `Accept-Languages` request header. If you do that, then generate the appropriate `<meta name="gwt:property" content="locale=XX">` so the GWT app bootstrap (the `.nocache.js` file) won't have to guess it too, which could result in the GWT app running in a different locale than the one the HTML was generated with.

Comment: You mean to use smth like http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Intl/MultilingualJSP/ ?

Comment: For instance. See also http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/ServerSideLocaleSelection to help determine the locale to use, depending on the ones available for your GWT app and the `Accept-Languages` request header.